# How to scanf a sequence

Tags: c

I am a complete noobie in c and we were given our first homework.

The first input should look like this

```
212 -78 5 16 32
```

And this should be the output

```
212, -78, 5, 16, 32
Amount of odd numbers: 1
Amount of even numbers: 4
```

This would not be a problem for me, but we have another input for the same code, which looks like this

```
140 128 8 1603 
4905 -3 -2 0 0 
9166 255 -1322 
8900 10000 -1 6543
```

And the output

```
140, 128, 8, 1603, 4905, -3, -2, 0, 0, 9166, 255, -1322, 8900, 10000, -1, 6543
Amount of odd numbers: 6
Amount of even numbers: 10
```

For the first input I would do something like this

```c
int a, b, c, d, e;
scanf("%d%d%d%d%d",&a ,&b, &c, &d, &e);
printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n",a ,b ,c ,d ,e);
```

But this obviously would not work for the second input. I reckon it might require using loops, but I have no idea. Thanks for any help you can give me

Comment: Use `fgets` in conjunction with `sscanf`. And read *one* number at a time.

Comment: If you're new at this, you've gotten the impression that `scanf` is how you do inout in C.  That's a false impression.  There are lots of ways of doing input in C.  (And they're *all* better than `scanf` in almost every way, but that's another story.)

Comment: But if you want to use `scanf`, just use it to read one number at a time. (And, yes, use it inside a loop so you can read an arbitrary number of numbers.)  One of the many surprises abount `scanf` -- which will probably actually work to your advantage here -- is that it doesn't care about whether the input is broken up into lines in a certain way or not.

Comment: See [A beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: Please learn to be consistent in your code layout — down to little details like "spaces after commas, no spaces before commas".  Your code fragment is not consistent.

Comment: Note that writing the code to check variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` is a lot more painful than code that reads one number at a time, or that uses an array.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It appears line breaks are not significant here, so using `fgets` would just make the code much more complex (two loops nested, needing to worry about max line length).

Answer (score 1):

The input will be buffered and `scanf()` will continue from where it left off, so you can use multiple `scanf()` calls in a loop to read the input one number at a time.

Also in this case there is no need to store all the input values is separate variables (or even more plausibly an array), you can evaluate the odd/even-ness of each input as they are entered, then discard the value:

```
int inchk = 0 ;
do
{
    int inp = 0 ;
    inchk = scanf( "%d", &inp ) ;

    if( inchk == 1 )
    {
        if( <test inp for even here> ) even++ ;
        else odd++
    }
} while( inchk == 1 ) ;
```

This loop will continue until something that is not a decimal integer is entered.  It is not clear how your input is to be terminated or entered, so the loop will need modification to cope with that perhaps.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : that was a mis-type on my part, not intentional.  Fixed.  Does not need to be _input failure_ end of redirected file would have the same effect.

Comment: I figured it was `:)`